# What kind of harware configuration choose for a game-oriented Ubuntu PC?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, hardware, games

I am considering buying newer hardware for my Ubuntu-only Box. The main purpose of the PC is gaming, mainly Humble Bundle games, some old Windows games with wine and web-based games (the facebook kind).

None of these games require *huge* hardware power, but still, a smooth experience would be nice.

The first issue is : how much RAM should I install ? Corollary : should I install a 32 or 64 bits system ? I fear that as much memory as 8Go won't be supported under 32bit, but I also fear to run into software problems with a 64 bits system...

Second question (But I believe it has always been asked many times) : which graphic card manufacturer offer better support these days ?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game-oriented? You could do 4GB 32/64-bit or 8GB 64-bit. You can run up to 64GB of RAM in 32-bit thanks to PAE (physical address extension) but it is probably best to switch to 64-bit. You should be able to run software perfectly in 64-bit and with chroot/VirtualBox, you can always run 32-bit software that (for whatever reason) doesn't work in 64-bit in an emulated 32-bit system.

Graphics card manufacturer? Well there is only really nVidia and AMD. Both seem to have proprietary drivers for Linux that you can use. I have had lots of problems with nVidia but I have an old GeForce 7050 (only 256MB of GRAM)...it's your choice really. It might make sense to go with an Intel CPU/nVidia GPU setup or an AMD CPU/AMD GPU setup. Your choice.

This is a little off-topic but it is Ubuntu specific ;)

Comment: Could you please detail the chroot solution ? Pointers to any kind of how-to would be nice...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot